# How to Convert Time in JAVA Swing into currency

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hello i have problem on how to convert my time into currency when i logout a customer in a computer timer server. commonly seen on internet café which they time the customer's pc and when the customer will logout the client server will display the amount of time he/she consumed and display how much would he/she be pay off.

```
    public ZipTimer() {

    lblTimer1 = new JLabel("New label");
    lblTimer1.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Light", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    lblTimer1.setBounds(103, 208, 190, 50);
    contentPane.add(lblTimer1);
     timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setTimer();
                seconds++;
            }
        });


    btnStart1 = new JButton("Start");
    btnStart1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    if(timer.isRunning()) {
                        timer.stop();
                        btnStart1.setText("Start");
                    }else {
                        timer.start();
                        btnStart1.setText("Stop");
                    }

        }
    });

    private void setTimer() {

    Date d = new Date(seconds * 1000L);
    String time = df.format(d);
    lblTimer1.setText(time);
```

Comment: So, you need to know the base amount per a given time unit (let's say 1cent per second - yeah I'm a greedy bastard), then it's simply a matter of times it by the number of seconds (`1 * seconds`)

Comment: A word of warning though, Swing `Timer` (and `Thread.sleep`) only guarantee a minimum delay, so the time between updates could be longer.  it would be better to capture the current time when the button is pressed and calculate the duration between it and the current time/time the button is pressed again

Comment: I hope this is purely a learning project? You don't want to this for real? Like this?

Comment: what do you mean @GhostCat ? i'm learning with this kind of project and i'm new in Java GUI swing..

Comment: its kinda like that @MadProgrammer but i can't figure which code i will use to calculate the time he/she consumed and display the amount he/she will pay off.

Comment: `Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, LocalDateTime.now())`, where `startTime` is an instance of `LocalDateTime` representing the time the timer was started. [Date/Time classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) which be a good place to start - With respect, there are any number of questions on how to do this, but look for those answers which are using the new Date/Time API included in Java 8

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that this isn't for a real project - as I think your code would have issues in the real world...

Comment: @MadProgrammer i will look forward with this..

Comment: this is for educational purposes only.. @GhostCat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are an approach, obviously it has a lot of things to improve (Validation of the events, set the results in only one label, etc) but for studying purposes I think it's ok.

```
 package com.stackoverflow.time;

 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import java.awt.GridLayout;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;

 public class SwingControlDemo {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JPanel controlPanel;

    private long startTime = 0;
    private long stopTime = 0;

    private static double factor = .01;

    public SwingControlDemo() {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingControlDemo swingControlDemo = new SwingControlDemo();
        swingControlDemo.showButtonDemo();
    }

    private void prepareGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Time is money");
        mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        statusLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);

        statusLabel.setSize(350, 100);

        controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
        mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
        mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void showButtonDemo() {
        headerLabel.setText("Click the button to start monetizing your time");

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");

        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                start();
                statusLabel.setText("Started");
            }
        });

        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                stop();
                long elapsed = getElapsedSeconds();
                double debt = convertToMoney(elapsed);
                statusLabel.setText("Finished. Elapsed " + elapsed + " seconds. You owe us: " + debt + " dollars");
            }
        });
        controlPanel.add(startButton);
        controlPanel.add(stopButton);

        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public long getElapsedSeconds() {
        long elapsed;
        elapsed = (stopTime - startTime);
        return (elapsed / 1000) % 60;
    }

    //Here you apply your conversion, you must change the factor
    public double convertToMoney(long elapsedTime) {
        return elapsedTime * factor;
    }
 }
```

[image]